# GDB remote debugging with gdbserver on zynq zc702: not listing the correct source code

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am trying to do GDB remote debugging using gdbserver, but cannot get the debugger to break at and list the correct source code. I am not sure of what I might be doing wrong so I am writing everything that I have done. I have just started using linux and all these things two weeks ago.

1. The host system for GDB is running **Debian using virtualbox on my windows 7 based laptop**.
2. The remote target running gdbserver is **xilinx zynq zc702 with Debian**.
3. The target code has been compiled using CodeSoucery compiler **arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc**, and correspondingly the GDB I am using is **arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb**.
4. First I login on the target using **ssh** and start gdbserver by typing in the terminal:

   ```
   root@zynq:/path/on/target# gdbserver localhost:3278 my_app.elf

   Process my_app.elf created; pid = 2083

   Listening on port 3278
   ```
5. Next I start GDB by typing in a host terminal:

   ```
   b51957@B51957debian:~$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb /path/on/host/my_app.elf
   ```

   GDB starts normally without any warnings and also shows this line:

   ```
   This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi".
   ```
6. Next I set the sysroot by typing on the host terminal:

   (gdb) set sysroot remote:/
7. Next I connect to the remote target by typing in the host terminal:

   ```
   target remote *target IP address*:3278
   ```

   In the Host terminal I get the following response:

   ```
   Remote debugging using *target IP address*:3278    
   Reading symbols from remote:/lib/ld-linux.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
   Loaded symbols for remote:/lib/ld-linux.so.3
   ```

   And in the target terminal I get the following response:

   ```
   Remote debugging from host *host IP address*
   ```
8. Now I ask it to put a breakpoint at line 23 in the main.cpp by typing in the host terminal:

   ```
   (gdb) break main.cpp:23
   ```
9. I then let it continue and then stop at the breakpoint, and then I try to list the source code. But instead of getting into my main.cpp file it always goes into some standard C++ library header (perhaps iostream). This is what the terminal looks like:

   ```
   (gdb) c

   Continuing.

   Breakpoint 1, 0x00009bdc in main ()

   (gdb) l

   11  // This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,

   12  // but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of

   13  // MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   ```

   and so on...

Please note that I am using the `-g` and `-o0` options for compilation, and also `-g` option for the linker. I have also tried to add the folder containing the source files to the  GDB source path by using the 'directory' command. The source path already contains `$cwd` and `$cdir`. I cant figure out why I am still unable to see my source code.

Comment: Use the backtrace "bt" command to see where your execution currently is.  Also, telnet/ssh into the target and examine the /proc/pid/maps and related files to see what is actually loaded at the address you are sitting at - is it code from your program, or one of the libraries?